# UpdateDatabase catches no exception but database doesn't update - C#, SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database

Thanks to everyone else's questions about this in here I am now more confused than before.

Preface

1) The coding you are about to see comes from a tutorial.

2) The connection works perfectly when it comes to reading data from the database. I can succesfully compare usernames and passwords to "login" to my system, I can check who has admin credentials and who is a basic user, etc.

3) The data types in my database are nvarchar(50) and money, so when the time comes to add data to my new row, I give strings to the nvarchar columns and decimal to the money column according to the SQL Server Data Type Mappings found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

4) My project has more than 3 forms, login happens in the 1st form, the 1st form opens the 2nd using ShowDialog(), the 2nd opens the 3rd using ShowDialog() and this is where I put the info of a new user and call the update. It throws no exceptions, I close form 3 and 2 and when I put the new username and password in form1 they do not match any entry in the database. When I return from running the project, no new entries are in the database.

*Note: all forms succesfully retrieve data from the database.

The Code (or at least the part of it that matters)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyGym
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        DatabaseConnection objConnect;
        string conString;
        DataSet ds;
        DataRow dRow;
        int MaxRows;

        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
                conString = Properties.Settings.Default.usersConnectionString;
                objConnect.connection_string = conString;
                objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;
                ds = objConnect.GetConnection;
                MaxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }

        private void userSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                    DataRow newRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
                    if (radCustomer.Checked) // Some radiobutton checks.
                    {
                        newRow[1] = "customer"; //String goes to nvarchar type
                    }
                    else if (radEmployee.Checked)
                    {
                        newRow[1] = "employee";
                    }
                    newRow[2] = userName.Text;
                    newRow[3] = autoPass.Text;
                    newRow[4] = firstName.Text;
                    newRow[5] = lastName.Text;
                    Decimal balance = 0m;
                    newRow[6] = balance; // Decimal goes to money data type
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);
                    try
                    {
                        objConnect.UpdateDatabase(ds);
                        MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                    }
        }

    }
}
```

I have ommitted code that searches the database for same firstName-lastName combo or same username and it works fine reading the database. But writing in it just doesn't happen.

My table's definition is this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [status]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [username]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [password]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [firstname] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [lastname]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [balance]   MONEY         NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Pretty simple stuf.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

And for the curious ones: this is for a university course project.

Thank you all in advance!

edit: The DatabaseConnection()

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyGym
{
    class DatabaseConnection
    {
        private string sql_string;
        private string strCon;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da_1;

        public string Sql
        {

            set { sql_string = value; }

        }

        public string connection_string
        {

            set { strCon = value; }

        }

        public System.Data.DataSet GetConnection
        {

            get { return MyDataSet(); }

        }

        private System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);
            con.Open();
            da_1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);
            System.Data.DataSet dat_set = new System.Data.DataSet();
            da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
            con.Close();
            return dat_set;
        }

        public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);
            cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DataSet` is a local copy and the values will be updated in the data set. call update method of your data adapter and that should fix this.

Comment: you didn't use namespace - `System.Data.SqlClient` ? How does you provide `ConnectionSrting` in your application?

Comment: MageshKumaar. the ds is indeed a local copy BUT I call 'objConnect.UpdateDatabase(ds);' which is supposed to "overwrite" the data in the database. objConnect does it job alright when fetching data from the database so why doesn't it also write new data? I don't have a data adapter, or I think I don't, since the code I used is copy-paste from a tutorial and it said nothing about data adapters. I am obviously a rookie here. I need baby steps. @Crowcoder Ok I'll work on to that. - Rahul, it fetches data just fine so I don't know what to tell you. - Thank you all for commenting!

Comment: @Crowcoder Oooh... I forgot to mention the DatabaseConnection. It is indeed a custom method and I am editing it in my post now.

Comment: @Crowcoder So I should not create the "cb" and only have "da_1.Update(ds.Tables[0]);" in that method? in a try-catch?

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank you so much. I am already looking into these thanks to you.

Comment: @Crowcoder Ok I looked. And no, I couldn't get the slightest basic understanding, now I am even MORE confused. It is supposed to automatically decide what to do on the existing database with the use of the updated dataset. That's the whole point of the SqlDataAdapter.Update() command. Also my SQL commands knowledge is zero. - @ anyone else reading this: I would greatly appreciate it if someone could give me the command I am supposed to give to my adapter. The point of this course project is human-computer interaction anyway and this is what I should be working on the most.

Comment: @Crowcoder what do you mean "if i want to use the builder"? There is nothing for me to choose if I want it or not. This example here is one of millions I had already found and if my knowledge was enough they should had been enough to figure out the solution.But I don't have the knowledge nor the time to build it! Also, the "queryString" surpasses me! I never post in here unless I really REALLY don't know what to do and get zero results no matter what I try. So please, with all due respect, stop throwing me things everyone can easily find on google search.